# Javascript inserting html between readyState loading and complete

Tags: javascript, appendchild, readystate

I'm looking for a way to insert html (tags) into a website at a specific location as early as possible.
The insertion it self is not an issue, I'm merely looking for a way to speed it up by not needing to wait for the readyState complete to fire.

I know that GTM (google tag manager) inserts the tags somewhere between loading and complete. How is it doing this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

document.readyState === 'interactive' seems to be the earliest event firing